# Not sure how to fix some 404 can find files errors

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

The project that I am currently working on has a couple of downloaded files needed to function. The example that I am following for this project has the files that they need entered as:

```
$var js: Static/js/bootstrap.min.js Static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js Static/js/scripty.js
```

but when I do the same thing for my code I get errors listed like:

```
GET /Static/js/scripty" - 404 Not Found
GET /Static/js/scripty.js" - 404 Not Found
GET /Static/js/bootstrap.min.js" - 404 Not Found
```

I don't know if the issue has something to do with the GET command that I use or if it can't locate the files. I have them stored in the same locations as the they should be and have deleted and re-downloaded to see if that solves the issue but they continue to not be found. I think that if I can solve this the register page problem would go away because the scripty file that it keeps not finding is part of a JQuery code set that helps handle the registration information. This is the controller page of the project I am working that contains the GET commands:

```
import web 
from Models import RegisterModel

urls = (
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register', 'Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration'
)

render = web.template.render("Views/Templates", base="MainLayout")
app = web.application(urls, globals())


class Home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Home()


class Register:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Register()


class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()

        reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
        return data.username

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The files that it says that it can't find are stored in a folder labeled Static then another folder named js and I can find them easily on the project taskbar on the side of the compiler so I know that they are downloaded to be used. That's all the information I can really provide that I think outlines the problems I'm running into. If your familiar with the problem please let me know how to resolve it. Here is the content of the scripty file that it is trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("loaded");
    $.material.init();

    $(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#register-form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/postregistration',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        }):
    });
}):

This is the other page of code where the the scripty JQuery file is called.

$def with (page)
$var js: Static/js/bootstrap.min.js Static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js Static/js/scripty.js

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodeMage</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Static/js/scripty"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id ="app">
        <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color:#e3f2fd;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">CodeMage</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="waves-effect" href="/">Home Feed<div class="ripple container"></div></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="discover">Discover<div class="ripple container"></div></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="profile">Profile<div class="ripple container"></div></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="settings">Settings<div class="ripple container"></div></a></li>
            </ul>&nbsp;

            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="/Login" class="btn btn-link waves-effect">Login</a>&nbsp;
                <a href="/register" class="btn btn-raised btn-default waves-effect">Register</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
```

Comment: Just to verify that the current URL of the browser isn't affecting it, I would include `/` before `Static` in your script tags. So `Static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js` becomes `/Static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js`, `Static/js/scripty` becomes `/Static/js/scripty.js`. Also in your HTML you are referring to `scripty` not `scripty.js`.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll give that a shot. I emailed the guy who lectures the course but they never get back to me.